# Finding the area between two curves bounded by upper and lower limits

Tags: calculus

Find the area of the region R enclosed by the line $$y=2x+6$$ and the parabola $$y^2=12x+252$$

I am currently stuck with this question at a certain step, can someone help explain to me what I am doing wrong?

My work:

$$S(1) = x = (y-6)/2$$
$$S(2) = x = (y^2 - 252) / 12$$

after that we get the points of intersection which is:

$$18, -12$$

after that I did  S(1) - S(2) and got this:

$$(1/12)(-y^2 + 6y - 216)$$

Then I took the integral and got

$$ (1/12)((-y^3)/3 + 3y^2 - 216y))$$

Then I plugged in the upper and lower limits 19 and -11, but I still got the answer wrong.. This is my 3rd attempt doing this and I still cannot get the answer in the book. This is a horizontal type question of areas between two curves.

Comment: I would plot the functions to see how "rotating the figure by 90 degrees" (i.e., integrate by dy rather than dx) will simplify your integration significantly.

Comment: I'm still not sure where I went wrong in my work?

Comment: Graph the two functions and you will see your error.  The integration is *NOT* merely between the two intersection points.

Comment: I also integrated by dy and then minused it but still not right answer, I can't seem to find the error in my work.

Comment: Don't you just take the integral and then plug in F(18) - F(-12)..?

Comment: No you don't.  There are *TWO* regions to be integrated, not *ONE* (as you imagine).  If you don't graph these functions, you will never understand your error.  Please graph them and save yourself lots of time, and increase your understanding.

Comment: When you took the integral, shouldn't you get $-216y$ and not $-216x$? (This is a good reason to include the $dy$ in your integrals.)

Comment: My bad, it's supposed to be y like you said. But I am definitely taking the integral with respect to y.

Comment: I graphed this and I still am not understanding where I went wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope you understand from this figure why you need two integrals:

[image]